# jQuery slide repeated code

Tags: jquery, slide

I would like top know if there is a way to create several slides and panels using minimal code and avoid this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slide1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#slide2").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

As you can see, for every pair of panel and slide I have to create 3 new lines of jQuery. Is there a way to avoid this? I'm open to solutions that use Javascript as well. The goal of this is to simply have a few lines of code, and for every panel and slide involved, I don't have to add any code whatsoever. I simply have to add a slide and panel, and it will function.

Comment: Give all your slides a class, like `class="slides"`. Put the click event on all of them with a single handler, like `$(".slides").click()`. Strip the word `slide` from the current ID: `var slideNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("slide","");` so you're left with a number, and concatenate it to the panel like so: `$("#panel" + slideNumber).slideToggle("slow");`.

Comment: Yes you can based on your HTML you can use `$(this)` or `index()` or many other ways to make the relation between each slide and panel. Include your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including your HTML would be very important in this case. Depending on the relationship between your panels and slides, you may be able to make use of `.siblings()`, `.parent()`, `children()`, etc.

However, assuming they're not related at all and need to be selected by unique ID...

---

Give all your slides a common class:

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide3" class="slide"></div>
```

Put the handler on the common class instead of separate ID's, and get the "slide number", using `$(this)` to refer to the clicked slide. You can get the ID and remove the word "slide" from it, so all you're left with is the "slide number". Then, `"#panel" + slideNumber` should give you the associated panel.

```
$(".slide").click(function(){
    var slideNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("slide","");
    $("#panel" + slideNumber).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

---

As [DaniP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887133/danip) suggests in the comments below, if your slides are the only elements that begin with the word "slide", you could use a wildcard selector to match them by "ID starting with 'slide'", like so:

```
$([id=^"slide"]).click(function() { ... });
```

You wouldn't need to implement the common class as I suggested earlier in this case.

Comment: Even simpler don't use a common class you can use an attr selector like `$([id=^"slide"])`

Comment: Yeah @DaniP I considered that, it's just a bit hazy because often times these implementations have things like `id="slide-container"` as a parent, etc. You were correct in requesting the HTML and perhaps I was a bit hasty in posting my answer, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: No now your first paragraph make the clarification nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `each()` function in jquery for this. Similar to what Santi suggested, you'll first need a common identifier to capture each element you want in your query. You can do what he said and add a class manually to each element. You can also use a 'begins with' (`^`) to match elements with an `id` that begins with 'panel'. Then inside the `each()` function, you will use the `$(this)` variable to refer to the DOM element that you want to add `slideToggle()` to:

js:

```
$('[id^=panel]').each(function(){
    /* Comment
       Inside this function, "$(this)" would be the element
       just the same as if you said: $('#panel1')
    End Comment */

    $(this).click(function(){
        slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

`$('[id^=panel]')` is how you would match elements with an `id` starting with 'panel'.

Comment: Well for one, this doesn't hide a specific panel, it hides *all* of them. And that being taken into account, why loop through them if you're just going to hide them all? If this were the intent, `$('[id^=panel]').slideToggle('slow');` would suffice.

Comment: @Santi I wrote too fast; forgot to add the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a data attribute on the click targets (*the `#slideXX`*) that points to the panel to toggle

```
<div data-panel-target="#panel1"></div>
<div id="#panel1"></div>
```

and use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-panel-target]").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).data('panel-target');
        $(target).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```